# Для чего шифруется ID вопроса на google

Tags: php, шифрование, md5

Если пройти по URL любого из вопросов от гугл, то можно заменить, что в URL id шифруется.
tid=5471e25970befe0b
Кто может объяcнить для чего?

Comment: Чтобы не подбирали наверно :)

Answer (score 0):

Как я знаю, это некая защита от XSS.